# HowTo set a border around a Canvas in Javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx, canvas, border

I'm new to JavaFX and I just can't figure out why my following attempt to set a simple border around my JavaFX-Canvas (the **TilesViewer** class in this example extends a **Canvas**) with the means of CSS does not have any effect.

I want to use the method setStyle() and inline CSS (no external file).

```
private void initMinimap() {

    final double width = this.model.getTiles().length * 1.0;
    final double height = this.model.getTiles()[0].length * 1.0;        
    final TilesViewer minimap = new TilesViewer(this.model.getTiles(),
            width, height);


    minimap.setLayoutX(this.getWidth() - minimap.getWidth() * 1.1);
    minimap.setLayoutY(
            this.getHeight() - TOOLBAR_HEIGHT - minimap.getHeight() * 1.1);


    minimap.getStyleClass().add("minimap");
    final String css = ".minimap {-fx-border-color: green ;}";
    minimap.setStyle(css);

    minimap.autoScale();
    minimap.render();

    this.getChildren().add(minimap);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Draw border around a Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083027/draw-border-around-a-canvas)

Comment: Thanks, but I already viewed this answer before I posted my problem, but I want to use the method setStyle() of Canvas und use CSS inline. It has to work somehow ... ?

Comment: No, that won't work because `Canvas` is not a `Region` and it's the latter class which defines a `border` property.

Comment: ah, ok, now I understand. So, if I would wrap this Canvas in a Pane (which is a Region), it should work?

Comment: Yes, as long as you apply the border to the `Pane`. That said, if you look at [James_D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27092677/6395627) in the duplicate you'll see he uses a `StackPane`. You may want to do so as well since, as far as I can tell, `Pane` does not take the border or padding into account when laying out its children.

Comment: You cannot include selectors in your inline css style. Inline css styles must contain rules only, so even if your class did provide a `-fx-border-color` property, this kind of style wouldn't work; you'd need to use `-fx-border-color: green;` (and you wouldn't be required to also add the style class to apply that rule.

Answer (score 1):

Should work fine - in one implementation I used the `setStyle` method to apply this style to the image when the image is clicked. Wrap your image in a `BorderPane`.

```
"-fx-border-color:lightblue ; -fx-border-insets:3; -fx-border-radius:7; -fx-border-width:1.0"
```